# Better Way To Join Two Tables Based On Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

```
Table1

    id |   Name   | Car     |  
    ---+----------+---------+
     1 |   Jake   |   BMW     |
     2 |   Smith  |   Audi    | 
     3 |   Jake   |   Benz    | 
     4 |   Jake   |   Tesla   | 
     5 |   Jake   |   Jaguar  |  
     6 |   Smith  |   Toyoyta | 
     7 |   Andrew |   Bike    |
     8 |   Jake   |   BMW     |
```

and
Table2

```
    id |   Name   | Car1    | Car2    | Car3     |  Car3    |
    ---+----------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
     1 |   Jake   | Nissan  |  BMW    |  Tesla   | Jaguar   |
     2 |   Smith  | Audi    |  Toyota |   Ford   |          |
     3 |   Andrew | Bike    |  BMW    |   Jaguar |  Prius   |
```

I would like to have a JOIN based on first the **Name** from both [Table1] and [Table2] as well as columns condition on ***[Table1.Car] vs [Table2.Car1]*** and ***[Table1.Car2] vs [Table2.Car1]*** and ***[Table1.Car] vs [Table2.Car3]***

So for example, a JOIN for Jake would return the below because Jake does not have a Nissan in [Table2].

```
    id |   Name   | Car2    | Car3    |  Car3   |
    ---+----------+---------+---------+---------+
     1 |   Jake   |   BMW   |  Tesla  |  Jaguar |
```

I have tried a INNER JOIN below

```
select DISTINCT(a.Name) from Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b ON a.Name = b.Name 
AND b.Car1 = a.Car OR b.Car2 = a.Car OR b.Car3 = b.Car 
where b.Name='Jake'
```

This result is returning some columns  but it doesn't print out all the matching columns and I suspect is because of the OR conditions.

Is there a better way to achieve the above result?

Comment: 2 Car3 cols? Typo?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing some parentheses:

```
select DISTINCT(a.Name) from Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b ON a.Name = b.Name 
AND (b.Car1 = a.Car OR b.Car2 = a.Car OR b.Car3 = b.Car)
where b.Name='Jake'
```

AND is a higher precedence over OR, so your query evaluates to this:

```
select DISTINCT(a.Name) from Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b ON
(a.Name = b.Name AND b.Car1 = a.Car)
OR b.Car2 = a.Car OR b.Car3 = b.Car
where b.Name='Jake'
```

Which is probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To print also all the columns from Table2, then you also need to `SELECT` them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, b.*
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b 
  ON a.Name = b.Name
 AND a.Car IN (b.Car1, b.Car2, b.Car3)
WHERE a.Name='Jake'
```

For this, using an `IN` also works.

The `LEFT JOIN` is to show all from Table1, even when there's no match with Table2.
And then the `WHERE` clause looks for `a.Name`, instead of `b.Name`.
Or it would behave as an `INNER JOIN`.

But if you're looking for records in Table1 for the missing Car per Name?

Then you could filter on `b.Name IS NULL`, to only find the unmatched.

```
SELECT a.Name, a.Car
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b 
  ON a.Name = b.Name
 AND a.Car IN (b.Car1, b.Car2, b.Car3)
WHERE a.Name='Jake'
  AND b.Name IS NULL
GROUP BY a.Name, a.Car
```